# Is there a way to get all of a DOMElement's attributes?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I'm reading some XML with PHP and currently using the `DOMDocument` class to do so. I need a way to grab the names and values of a tag's (instance of `DOMElement`) attributes, without knowing beforehand what any of them are. The [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) doesn't seem to offer anything like this. I know that I can get an attribute's value if I have its name, but again, I don't know either of these and need to find both.

I also know that other classes like `SimpleXMLElement` have this capability, but I'm interested in how it can be done with `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get all the attributes of a given DomNode, using the [DomNode->attributes](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) property, it will return you [DOMNamedNodeMap](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php) containing the attribute names and values.

```
foreach ($node->attributes as $attrName => $attrNode) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a note that the docs you linked to are for PHP4. For those using PHP5 (like me), this is the more recent documentation: http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes

Comment: This is wrong. The foreach gives you DOMNodes, which have a nodeName and nodeValue property.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to get attribute name and attribute values (not the attributeNodes) you have to call the $attrNode->nodeValue property of the DOMNode object.

```
$attributes = array();

foreach($element->attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_node)
{
  /** @var  DOMNode    $attribute_node */
  $attributes[$attribute_name] = $attribute_node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This one is the more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon this question while searching for a way to convert node attributes to an array in order to compare that array against results from database. Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/264502/jan-molak does do the trick, but for my case it does not account for the fact, that some attributes may be missing in the node or that they may be empty strings, while there are `NULL`s returned from DB.
To cover this I've expanded it into below function, that may be of use to someone else, as well:

```php
    #Function to convert DOMNode into array with set of attributes, present in the node
    #$null will replace empty strings with NULL, if set to true
    #$extraAttributes will add any missing attributes as NULL or empty strings. Useful for standartization
    public function attributesToArray(\DOMNode $node, bool $null = true, array $extraAttributes = []): array
    {
        $result = [];
        #Iterrate attributes of the node
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
            if ($null && $attrValue === '') {
                #Add to resulting array as NULL, if it's empty string
                $result[$attrName] = NULL;
            } else {
                #Add actual value
                $result[$attrName] = $attrValue->textContent;
            }
        }
        #Add any additional attributes, that are expected
        if (!empty($extraAttributes)) {
            foreach ($extraAttributes as $attribute) {
                if (!isset($result[$attribute])) {
                    if ($null) {
                        #Add as NULL
                        $result[$attribute] = NULL;
                    } else {
                        #Or add as empty string
                        $result[$attribute] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #Return resulting string
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I've replaced `nodeValue` with `textContent`, because somehow it feels a bit more "natural" to me, when speaking about attributes, but technically they will be the same here regardless.
If required, this function is avialable in Composer as part of `Simbiat/ArrayHelpers` (https://github.com/Simbiat/ArrayHelpers)