# PHP: getAttribute() all attributes

Tags: php, dom, attributes

I can get the attribute of the tag tragetting ID by:

```
$tag_id = $tag->getAttribute('id');
```

But I want to get **all** attributes, not just `id`. How can I do this? I tried `getAttribute("*")` but it did not work (obviously).

Comment: I dont have any experiences on it, but I found two posts from SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385834/php-dom-get-all-attributes-of-a-node, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338692/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-of-a-domelements-attributes, I hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the public `$attributes` property from the DOMNode element that the DOMElement inherits from. See also here in the documentation: [DOMNode::$attributes](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes)

Code example:

```
$document = <<<DOCUMENT
<div id='one' style='width: 10px'></div>
DOCUMENT;

$document = DOMDocument::loadXML($document);
$element = $document->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

$attributes = $element->attributes;
for ($i = 0; $i < $attributes->length; $i++) {
    $item = $attributes->item($i);
    echo 'There is an attribute called: "' . $item->nodeName . '" with value: ' . $item->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

See also the eval.in that I created: https://eval.in/494934